# Upload multiple files with curl

Tags: php, file, curl, upload

How do I upload multiple files in an array using `CURLFile` and `curl_setopt`?

Using the data array as it would throw an error (can't convert an array to a string) and `http_build_query` on the data would corrupt the `CURLFile` objects.

The data I have to upload looks like that:

```
[
    'mode' => 'combine',
    'input' => 'upload',
    'format' => $outputformat,
    'files' => [
        [0] => CURLFile object,
        [1] => CURLFile object,
        [x] => ...
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP 5.5+ has a function to create files without using CURLFile: [`curl_file_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php).

You can upload multiple files like this:

```
<?php

$files = [
    '/var/file/something.txt',
    '/home/another_file.txt',
];

// Set postdata array
$postData = ['somevar' => 'hello'];

// Create array of files to post
foreach ($files as $index => $file) {
    $postData['file[' . $index . ']'] = curl_file_create(
        realpath($file),
        mime_content_type($file),
        basename($file)
    );
}

$request = curl_init('https://localhost/upload');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($request);

if ($result === false) {
    error_log(curl_error($request));
}

curl_close($request);
```

This will be received on the server as an array under `file` the same as if there was a posted form, this is `$_FILES`:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.txt
                    [1] => 2.txt
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                    [1] => text/plain
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /private/var/folders/cq/7262ntt15mqdmylblg9p1wf80000gn/T/phpp8SsKD
                    [1] => /private/var/folders/cq/7262ntt15mqdmylblg9p1wf80000gn/T/php73ijEP
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

This is `$_POST`:

```
Array
(
    [somevar] => hello
)
```

Comment: The problem is that the server is an API and the files must be placed in a "files" array.

Comment: Are they expecting files to be an array of files like you posted the data or an array of files in some other format such as a base64 encoded string of the file contents?

Comment: Either files or base64, but the latter option is discouraged for big files.

Comment: It does not work. My array seems well formed (`files[0] => CURLFile Object, files[1] => CURLFile Object, ...`) but `curl_exec` run until the timeout...

Comment: it does not work. I've tried a lot, but I'm facing exactly the same challenge here, to send multiple files to an API via CURL.

Answer (score 5):

The index is part of the key

```
[
    'mode' => 'combine',
    'input' => 'upload',
    'format' => $outputformat,
    'files[0]' => CURLFile object,
    'files[1]' => CURLFile object,
    'files[x]' => CURLFile object
     ...
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is the old questions but I faced the same problem as well. I haven't found solution for cURL but was able to solve the problem using file_get_contents.
Note that I use *the same key* for all of the files.

Example:

```
/* Prepare request */
$multipartBoundary = "--------------------------" . microtime(true);
$contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary={$multipartBoundary}";
$content = "";

// Files
$paramName = "files";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileBaseName = basename($file);
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
    $content .= "--{$multipartBoundary}\r\n";
    $content .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$paramName}\"; filename=\"{$fileBaseName}\"\r\n";
    $content .= "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n{$fileContent}\r\n";
}

// Regular params
foreach ($params $key=>$value) {
    $content .= "--{$multipartBoundary}\r\n";
    $content .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"\r\n\r\n{$value}\r\n";
}

// End
$content .= "--{$multipartBoundary}--\r\n";

// Create context
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => [
    'header' => "Content-type: {$contentType}",
    'method'  => "POST",
    'timeout' => 5, // Seconds
    'content' => $content,
    'ignore_errors' => true // Do not report about HTTP errors as PHP Warnings
]]);



/* Send request */
$apiUrl = "https//api.example.com";
$endpoint = "/upload";
$url = $apiUrl . $endpoint;
$body = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$headerInfo = explode(" ", $http_response_header[0]);
$code = (int)$headerInfo[1];
$message = implode(" ", array_slice($headerInfo, 2));



/* Return result */
return [$body, $code, $message];
```

Comment: This is the only way I could get it working, thanks for sharing!