# PHP - cURL file upload

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm writing a script to uploading images to a specific api. Uploading one image is not a problem but more than one. The API documentation says the following:

```
curl -v -s -u username:password \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.de.xxx.api+json" \
-F "image=@img1.jpeg;type=image/jpeg" \
-F "image=@img2.jpeg;type=image/jpeg" \
-XPUT 'https://services.xxx.de/seller-api/sellers/123/ads/123/images'
```

My script:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$images = array(
    'image' => new CURLFile('PATH\1.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image')
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://services.xxx.de/seller-api/sellers/123/ads/123/images');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $images);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'USERNAME:PASSWORD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: services.xxx.de',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Accept: application/vnd.de.xxx.api+json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

The problem is that the api delete other images if I'm uploading a new one. But I can't write an array with multiple same keys like that:

```
$images = array(
    'image' => new CURLFile('PATH\1.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image'),
    'image' => new CURLFile('PATH\2.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image')
);
```

So the question is how I can set multiple CURLFiles with the same index like the curl command in the documentation?

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474192/upload-multiple-files-with-curl, May it will help you.

Comment: No, unfortunately not because the api respond: {"errors":[{"key":"unsupported-form-element"}]} That means that the key of the cURL-File MUST be "image" and nothing other... but thank you very much!

Comment: then try your Curl call in looping.

Comment: We talking about http://services.mobile.de/docs/seller-api.html ? Their documentation sure does have multiple "image" named multipart form datas with different file names... how odd

Comment: The problem is that the api delete other images if i´m uploading a new one @RWS.Piyush

Comment: Can you just use an array of CURLFile objects without your keyed index? They do construct a CLI curl request with that duplicate "image" name. Your third constructor param is the same value I'd assume.

Comment: Yeah right @Scuzzy ;) i hate that api :P

Comment: No i cant because the api says: {"errors":[{"key":"unsupported-form-element"}]} It must be an array with "image" as key...

Answer (score 0):

Working at mobile seller api ;-)
Here's the solution:
1. create an array of image-files like this one:

```
$count=0;
$files['image'.$count] = curl_file_create(#a#, 'image/jpeg', #b#)
$count++;
```

-> #a# full qualified path to your file on your server
-> #b# optionally a name for the image in the form 'image'.$count

Important: the array-key MUST be namend exactly in this way while you can name your array as you want ;-)

2. Options for curl: - remove the "host" from your HTTP_HEADER
   and add CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT with a value in seconds ;-)

By the way, in all actual php versions, we use TRUE and FALSE instead of 0 and 1 as values for curl-options.

It works for me ...

Answer (score -1):

My experience after hours of searching: 
With the official curl function, you can not make an multiple-upload of images.

You can only upload multiple images using the shell command.
Solution: Extend the shell script to include all images to be uploaded, then "shell_exec ($ str)" or exec ($ str). For me this works.