# sending multiple files with curl

Tags: php, arrays, api, curl, post

I am trying to send sending multiple files with curl using "CURLfile" my problem is every time only one file is sent.

I am making array of files inside curl postfileds

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://app.karzoun.chat/api/v1/accounts/1/conversations/63/messages',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('attachments[]'=> new CURLFILE('gAbs95dfl/karzoun whatsapp api.jpg'),'attachments[]'=> new CURLFILE('gAbs95dfl/karzoun-security.png'),'content' => 'test','message_type' => 'outgoing'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'api_access_token: uKigRL93m5MjdzC2rm4dHCjr'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I tried to output the array using var_dump and YES it is only showing one object from array not both, this curl command I copied from postman, when trying it at postman it works and send multiple files, but in my php code not working.

```
    $array = array('attachments[]'=> new CURLFILE('https://karzoun.app/assets/uploads/karzoun/zapier.png'),'attachments[]'=> new CURLFILE('https://karzoun.app/assets/uploads/karzoun/zapier.png'));
 var_dump($array);
```

The Output if var_dump

```
array(1) { ["attachments[]"]=> object(CURLFile)#2 (3) { ["name"]=> string(53) "https://karzoun.app/assets/uploads/karzoun/zapier.png" ["mime"]=> string(0) "" ["postname"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474192/upload-multiple-files-with-curl help?

Comment: Why not use `Guzzle` library? That is much easier to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload multiple files with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474192/upload-multiple-files-with-curl)